# Showing/Hiding groups of markers using layers or some other grouping method

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I have a set of markers which I want to have visible or not on a React Google map.

In ESRI/ArcGIS maps you can create layers which can be turned on or off, but it does not seem any equivalent features exist in Google maps.

I suppose can give the markers a specific class and turn their visibility on or off, but I am concerned this may impact performance.

Any suggestions on a way forward?

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API does not support this kind of custom layers (refer [official docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers) for a supported list of layers).
The following custom component demonstrates how to group markers and toggle its visibility

```
function MarkersGroup(props, context) {
  const layersRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const map = context[MAP];
    let layers = null;
    if (!layersRef.current) {
      layers = new window.google.maps.MVCObject();
      for (let name in props.groupData) {
        for (let item of props.groupData[name].items) {
          const markerProps = { position: { lat: item.lat, lng: item.lng } };
          const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker(markerProps);
          marker.bindTo("map", layers, name);
        }
      }
      layersRef.current = layers;
    } else layers = layersRef.current;

    for (let name in props.groupData) {
      if (props.groupData[name].visible) {
        layers.set(name, map);
      } else {
        layers.set(name, null);
      }
    }
  });

  return null;
}
```

Notes:

- [`google.maps.MVCObject` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/event#MVCObject) - is used to store layer(markers) group
- layer visibility is toggled via [`MVCObject.set` method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/event#MVCObject.set)

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lkrsfc)